# Independent variable has a known non-causal relationship with the dependent variable; is it still okay to regress?

Tags: time-series, data-imputation

To further elaborate on my question, assume that I have a time series dataset of Tax X and Tax Y, where in Tax X is paid by 100% of the sample while Tax Y is paid by 75%. Both taxes differ with regards to how they are implemented and collected, but are ultimately based on business revenues. Now if I am trying to figure out the relationship between Tax Y and Tax X to estimate Tax Y for the 25% of the sample for which there is no Tax Y data, is it kosher to regress Tax Y on Tax X? It is clear to see that Tax X is not causing Tax Y and that both taxes are being determined by individual business revenues, which is not known.

Answer (score 3):

There can be a linear relationship between variables with no causal relation directly involved. It's fair to check if the linear model is a good fit in order to make estimations.

I personally don't know any single model which needs something like *"direct causality assumption"*.

Comment: Interesting. I don't have too much experience with time series data, but I was under the impression that since you have a greater degree of ability to identify and establish things like Granger causality, regression specifications with spurious relationships like the one I laid out were not considered useful.

Comment: +1 In the absence of a causal idnetification strategy, linear regression is just a handy descriptive or predictive tool. Apply as necessary, where necessary.